# Создание запроса с группировкой по трем не связанным таблицам

Tags: sql, база-данных

Даны 3 таблицы в СУБД MS Access.

Таблица "Отделы": название отдела, номер отдела.

Таблица "Малоценка": номер отдела к которому относится запись, наименование товара, кол-во принятых и списанных товаров и цена.

Таблица "Основные": номер отдела к которому относится запись, наименование товара, кол-во принятых и списанных товаров и цена.

[image: Таблица Малоценка]

[image: Таблица Основные]

[image: Таблица отделы]

В таблицах "Основные" и "Малоценка" может быть по несколько записей относящихся к одному отделу. Между этими таблицами нет никакой связи (по условию связей быть не должно).
Необходимо разработать запрос, который будет группировать записи из таблиц "Малоценка" и "Основные" по номеру отдела из таблицы "Отделы". При группировке будет суммировать цену принятых и списанных товаров для каждого отдела. В итоге должен получится такой результат:
[image: Результат запроса]

Пробовал делать группировку по полю "Отдел" из таблицы Отделы, но получается вот такое:
[image: Не правильный результат запроса]

SQL запроса:

```
SELECT Отделы.Отдел, 
Sum([Основные]![Прийнято][Основные]![Цена]) AS ПрийнятоОсн, 
Sum([Основные]![Списано][Основные]![Цена]) AS СписаноОсн, 
Sum([Основные]![Прийнято][Основные]![Цена]) - Sum([Основные]![Списано][Основные]![Цена]) AS НаличиеОсн, 
Sum([Малоценка]![Прийнято][Малоценка]![Цена]) AS ПрийнятоМал, 
Sum([Малоценка]![Списано][Малоценка]![Цена]) AS СписаноМал, 
Sum([Малоценка]![Прийнято][Малоценка]![Цена]) - Sum([Малоценка]![Списано][Малоценка]![Цена]) AS НаличиеМал
FROM Отделы, Основные, Малоценка
GROUP BY Отделы.Отдел;
```

Как правильно реализовать группировку для этого запроса?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не понятно что за результат Вы хотите получить. Результирующая таблица не отражает каких либо подробностей Вашей задачи.

Comment: inner join всех таблиц по полю Отдел